# jquery append method fails

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a web based and i'm using phonegap on android.
I have an ajax call that returns a html data that contain a few pages, and in the end i perform append to the body tag, and open one of the new pages.
most of the times it works perfectly, and their are a few cases that the append of that html
fails, and i dont have any idea why.
I tried to perform the ajax url call directly on my browser and i get a good result.

is their a way to get the error that  the append method accourd so i can fix it?
also are their limits on append method that some how works on browser that doesn't works on android?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share some code please.